# in vscode, when i type clg, i should be given the console.log() suggestion first, instead i get something else, why?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, code-snippets, autosuggest

i am using vscode as my editor, and i'm making a small meteo app in nextjs. For a few days, i've been having a problem that i can't seem to solve.

Example 1: when i type clg, the editor is supposed to give me the suggestion for the console.log() snippet first, then other suggestions ...
Instead i get suggested "WiCloudyGusts" (a reac icon) that contains the letters c, l and g.
In order to have the desired effect, i have to type clg, then press escape to remove the suggestion popup, then delete the g letter and type g again, only then i'll have the console.log() snippet suggested at the top.

Example 2: I have an extension for arrow functions snippets too, and it does the same thing when i try when i try to type "aafee", which should give me the following suggestion

```
Arrow async function (without return) (Arrow Function Snippets)

async () => {
    
}
```

instead it suggests me AnimationEffect for the following

```
interface AnimationEffect
var AnimationEffect: {
    new (): AnimationEffect;
    prototype: AnimationEffect;
}
```

same here, in order to have the desired suggestion put first, i have to delete the last e from "aafee" then type it again ...

i'm at a loss here, i've tried a bunch of things including adding

```
  "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
```

to my settings.json.

edit: i've also tried clearing cache, then disabling all my extensions except for the snippets one, restarting vscode, and reactivating all extensions 1 by 1 to see which one was causing the problem.

but the problem persists ...

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this this?: [Visual Studio Code's recent update is disrupting autocompletion](/q/75340072)

Comment: thanks for you answering, apparently this was it, i tried a bunch of different fixes, none of them worked. This morning when i started vscode after i reverted all these changes, it just came back to normal.